# Using procedural texture mask to drive displacement and base color

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

Very basic question: if I use a noise as mask for the displacement, how can I reference it in the node editor to use it as base color?
Thank you!

Comment: Modifier textures and Cycles nodes are completely separate and unrelated technologies. You can't cross reference or reuse them out of their contexts, as far as I know

Comment: That's a shame. Do you know a work-around?